# JPanel doesn't paint when frame.setUndecorated(true)

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

EDIT: After moving expressions around in the constructor, i currently managed to get it to draw it **sometimes** completely and **sometimes** partly.

I'm creating this game in Java2D and basically if I set setUndecorated(true) it doesn't paint anything in my panel anymore. The screen stays the background color black.

I initialize my frame like this:

```
panel = new WindowManager();

JFrame frame = new JFrame(Program.TITLE);
frame.setContentPane(panel);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setUndecorated(true);

frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
...
frame.setVisible(true);
```

And my WindowManager (extends JPanel) like this:

```
repaintTimer = new Timer(1000 / 60, e -> repaint());
repaintTimer.start();
setBackground(Color.black);

addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
...
```

The paintComponent Override starts with `super.paintComponent(g)`

Other code is kinda hard to give as it's a pretty big project.

I have no idea what causes this, so i was hoping one of you do.

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: So if you remove `frame.setUndecorated(true);` it works perfectly?

Comment: @Kayaman, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Asked an professor of mine,

Apparently having it fullscreen and putting it to undecorated changes screen mode in windows.

Settings the framesize to something small than the window size (like height, width-1) fixes it.